# how container logging works?

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes

I've seen in a lot of docker containers that it's a common practice to create a log file and log like this

```
/var/log/container.log
...

tail  -f /var/log/container.log
```

And somehow the output seems to be taken by the container runtime log driver. So if I run

```
docker container logs container
```

This will show the output of the file `container.log`

I know the best practice for any container is to log on `stdout` and `stderr`, but I can't understand why the first option works (create a file and run tail on it). Is it because the output of the `tail` is taken by the driver log and it merges it with the contents of stdout?

Really appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `tail -f` approach isn't really a best practice.

As you note, the right way to run a process and produce logs is to have it write its output directly to stdout and stderr, and `docker logs` will capture them.  You can configure Docker's logging layer to send them somewhere else; if you move to a clustered infrastructure like Kubernetes, you can configure its logging layer to capture logs as well, without modifying your application code.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am the script that runs the main container process.
# Run a single process, as a foreground process; when that
# process ends, the container exits.
exec some_server --no-daemon --log-file /dev/stdout
```

When you see `tail -f` it generally looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Start something as a background process.
something --log-file /var/log/something.log &
# Hackily keep the container from exiting.
tail -f /var/log/something.log
```

The main container process is the `tail` process.  When `tail` exits, the container will stop, and if you `docker stop` the container, the signal will go to `tail`.  Oh, by the way, as a side effect, there's a `something` process running, but if it fails Docker has no way of noticing it.  Still, since the `tail` process is the main process and `tail -f` will never exit, this keeps a container running, and it will make its file-based logs visible to the container's stdout.

Another interesting approach here is what the Docker Hub `httpd` image does: it sets its logging to point at a file, but the default content of that file is a symlink to `/dev/stdout`.

```sh
RUN mkdir /var/log/something \
 && ln -s /dev/stdout /var/log/something/something.log
CMD ["something", "--log-file", "/var/log/something/something.log"]
```

This is interesting because the default behavior will be to write things to that log file, but it's really the `/dev/stdout` special device, so it will go to the process's stdout (of the main container process).  If you want to capture this in a file instead, you can bind-mount your own directory over `/var/log/something` which will hind the symlink.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much David. Also, the symlink is a great suggestion.